# How do I optimise this ClickHouse DB JOIN query?

Tags: join, clickhouse

I am playing around with Clickhouse DB and I am trying to figure out why the query below is giving me a `DB::Exception: Memory limit (for query) exceeded` and could use some help...

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT created_at, rates.car_id, MIN(rates.price) FROM rates  
    WHERE 
        pickup_location_id = 198
        AND created_at = '2020-10-01'
    GROUP BY created_at, car_id 
) r
JOIN cars c2 ON r.car_id = c2.id
```

The inner query bit performs almost instantly (millions of records) and yields only 212 results. However, adding the JOIN causes the query to fail (memory exception, 45GB)

Looks like the JOIN happens on the whole of `rates`/`cars` - and not on the "result"?

Answer (score 0):

CH uses HASHJOIN and places the right table into memory into a HashTable.

In case of inner join you can swap tables:

```
SELECT * FROM cars c2 JOIN
(
    SELECT created_at, rates.car_id, MIN(rates.price) FROM rates  
    WHERE 
        pickup_location_id = 198
        AND created_at = '2020-10-01'
    GROUP BY created_at, car_id 
) r
ON r.car_id = c2.id
```

Comment: Ok thanks. It's not an inner join that's needed, but good to know anyway.

Comment: @TjeerdKramer   --join_algorithm arg                                             Specify join algorithm: 'auto', 'hash', 'partial_merge', 'prefer_partial_merge'. 'auto' tries to change HashJoin to MergeJoin on the fly to avoid out of memory.